# JSON String Escaping - MathJax

Tags: javascript, json, encode

I am trying to figure out how to have JS encode my MathJax string. Let's say I have:

```
\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\)
```

This fails a JSON lint test, but is the valid code I would use to make the equation appear inline. Is there any built in method to do this in JS?

```
componentURIEncode()
```

Is not giving an appropriate solution.

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.encode`? Also are you sure its JSON encoding you need?

Answer (score 3):

First, you can't have single backslashes in a JavaScript string.

Second, If you want to JSON encode an object, you need an object:

```
var MyMath = {};

MyMath.formula = "\\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\\)";

var jMath = JSON.stringify(MyMath);
```

Comment: I am aware of the single backslashes issue, but not sure how to get around it. My plan is to AJAX in that content, and then populate it with an Angular statement. Because of that, I need to store the equation as a JSON string (I think). If "\\(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\\)" is valid, perhaps my question should be how I get from the invalid string to the valid one?